# Windows 8.1 x64 random shutdowns after pc case change

Tags: windows-8.1, crash, shutdown

sadly we have another problem - changed the pc case and computer started to shutdown randomly.

Hardware/Software specs:

- CPU: s.2011 Intel E5-2660@2.6GHz with CNPS10X cooler, constant 52 to 54°C under load
- Motherboard: AsRock Extreme9 (stock settings)
- RAM: 8 × 4GB Kingston DDR3-1600 (tested, not faulty)
- Old videocard (when shutdowns started): RX 570 with 19.8.1 driver (around 65 to 72°C max under load)
- New videocard: Palit GTX1070 with 460.89 WHQL driver (around 66-67°C max under load)
- Marvel RAID 1: first 2 ports × WD 120GB SSD Green (healthy)
- LSI 9750-8i: RAID 10 - 4 drives 2TB Toshiba DT200 (healthy and cooled around 40°C)
- PSU: Seasonic S12-II 620W
- OS: Windows 8.1 x64
- SouthBridge: constant 45 to 51°C, no more

RX 570 was swapped due to impossibility to install the same driver on Win 8 and when crashes happened in first 5 minutes of PC usage after OS boot. Now with GTX 1070 driver is ok, but crashes continue to occur but more randomly (in the interval 30min to 3-4 hours). The other moment is when playing games - shutdown occurs after playing around 5-10 mins.

There's nothing in logs:

```
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

 EventData 

  BugcheckCode 0 
  BugcheckParameter1 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter2 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter3 0x0 
  BugcheckParameter4 0x0 
  SleepInProgress 0 
  PowerButtonTimestamp 0 
  BootAppStatus 0
```

No blue screen, no nothing - just a shutdown and that's it
Any ideas? Possible semi-short circuit somewhere or just dying motherboard/CPU/etc? Cables are properly attached - this system worked at least 2 years without problems with these components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower CPU frequency - longer OCCT test time. System survived at stock 2.2GHz, at 2.4GHz@allcores VR Loop 1 reached 98°C (while CPU is barely 50) and shutdowns despite already changed the VR thermal pads with better ones (Alphacool Thermal Pad 17W/mK)

For me there are two options for repair (assuming VRMs aren't faulty):

1. To replace original and crappy heatsinks with a taller ones and add fans to cool them
2. To replace pads with pure copper pads and add fans to cool the original heatsink contraption

Both are time consuming tasks, if someone has an idea what can be another highly plausible reason for the shutdowns

Answer (score 0):

Mother boards don't "die". There might be a loose connection, pinched wire, a partially unsoldered component on the PCB or a break in a PCB *trace*.

However, you state *shutdown occurs now with long or heavy use*, i.e., "crashes continue to occur but more randomly (in the interval 30min to 3-4 hours). The other moment is when playing games - shutdown occurs after playing around 5-10 mins." This indicates an issue with either cooling or a failing power supply.

1. Check that *all* fans spin up, increasing speed on heavy use. Run a CPU stress test, [olnine](https://cpux.net/cpu-stress-test-online) or as a [standalone app](https://listoffreeware.com/free-cpu-stress-test-software-windows/). See [Tom's Hardware](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/stress-test-cpu-pc-guide,5461.html) for usage.
2. Run [HwInfo](https://www.hwinfo.com/) or other hardware monitoring to check CPU temperature and voltage.
   [image: HwInfo temperature, voltage]
3. If you have access to another, perhaps larger, power supply, try substituting it for the current one.

Comment: PSU was tested first as a possible culprit and changed for ThermalTake ToughPower 750W. Both are fully stable at each voltage line under peak load, all protection features also work as intended. The only tool I didn't use was Intel® Processor Diagnostic Tool, will give it a go if this matters

Comment: Intel PTD - Pass on all test modules

Comment: Don't know the reason why but now first 5-6 minutes on OCCT shutdowns the machine on OCCT test or memory test on auto options. CPU or other components don't overheat nor the PSU gives overvoltages/undervoltages. Very weird, no MEMORY.DMP file created (it's enabled but file is not created), WHEA errors are zero when OCCT is started

Comment: Is it possible the phases are overheating (think the motherboard doesn't have sensors there)? Found a high frequency buzzing sound under a normal load and only moving the mouse